# How to check if a checkbox is checked ASP using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a checkbox and I want to detect on  a button click event if it's checked or not. I am using ASP MVC 5 and tried several methods but nothing worked for me. Here's the code:

```
$("#btnPrintVoucher").click(function () {
        if ($('#chkPrintSlip').prop('checked')) {
            alert("chked");
        }
        else {
            alert($('#chkPrintSlip').val());
        }
    });
```

Comment: It works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/fgsp6mb3/

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me as well. I gave a name to my input instead of id.

Comment: `#...` is strictly an ID selector.

Comment: Suggest you delete this question. No point cluttering up Stack Overflow more than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('#chkPrintSlip').is(':checked')) {
```

You can use `is(":checked")` to detect whether a checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I did this, you can see in my code. But it's not showing alert message even when  the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Can you share your HTML? I dont see any error in the JS

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me as well. I gave a name to my input instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

Using Vanilla JS:

```
if (document.getElementById('chkPrintSlip').checked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btnPrintVoucher").click(function () {
        if ($('#chkPrintSlip').is(':checked')) {
            alert("chked");
        }
        else {
            alert($('#chkPrintSlip').val());
        }
    });
```